# Value of an object is undefined

Tags: javascript, object, undefined, iife

I am learning JavaScript. I have tried the below code and I am seeing the value of an object as undefined. I expect the last console statement to print all the values in object v. My expectation is that this statement v.sampleFunction() will return "The given String is Sample String Sample String". And I thought I could print the same using **v.values**.Please advise me on where I am doing this wrong.

```js
var r;
var v = new Object();

(function() {
    // function 1
    function s(sampelString) {
        var t = "The given String is "+sampelString;
 return (t);
    }
    r = s("Sample Text");
    
    // Adding SampleFunction to v
    v.samepleFuntion = function() {
        s("Sample String Sample String");
    }
})();
v.samepleFuntion();
console.log("The values in r==="+r);
console.log("The values in v==="+v.values);
```

Comment: Please be more specific. What are you trying to achieve? Where and how are you experiencing the error?

Comment: It's really hard to tell what you expect that code to do, and it's not at all clear why it's written that way.

Comment: Umm, because you haven't defined `v.values` anywhere? As it stands, `v` was never given a property `values` (which is what you're trying to output), so it's undefined.

Comment: Sorry!
I expect the last console statement to print all the values in object v. My expectation is that this statement v.sampleFunction() will return "The given String is Sample String Sample String". And I thought I could print the same using v.values.

Comment: @BradChristie I'm going to go out on a limb and say BigDog was attempting to use this, albeit incorrectly: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values. Maybe OP can confirm?

Comment: @J.Titus Yeah. I did come across that and I have tried using that.

Comment: @J.Titus Agreed, and probably in IE where it's bound to be absent. ;-) Wasn't aware of that prop, though it is still in draft so makes sense (and I haven't exactly memorized every property/method of every object in JS). :grin: --yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to return the value of the function call

```
return s("Sample String Sample String");
//^^^^
```

```js
var r,
    v = new Object();

(function() {
    // function 1
    function s(sampelString) {
        var t = "The given String is "+sampelString;
        return (t);
    }
    r = s("Sample Text");
    
    // Adding SampleFunction to v
    v.samepleFuntion = function() {
        return s("Sample String Sample String");
        //^^^^
    }
})();

console.log("The values in r==="+r);
console.log(v.samepleFuntion());

console.log(Object.values(v));
```

Comment: How can I do the same using v.values() ?

Comment: you need a function assigned to `v.values`.

Comment: What I meant was that, will this statement return me anything?
console.log(Object.values(v));

Comment: [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) returns an array with the function, as you see it above. but it  works not on all browser. please see link.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can see the result. But I was executing the code in Cloud9 and it was giving me an error.